# “One of the regulars AT/OF/ON my balcony”

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

Speaking of a bird that often visits my balcony, which of the following expressions would be more correct and idiomatic?

1. One of the regulars **at** my balcony.
2. One of the regulars **of** my balcony.
3. One of the regulars **on** my balcony.

Or is it perhaps the case that none of these are idiomatic and another expression would be better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"On" or "at" both work. "Of" doesn't really work in this context.

"On" usually means *on the surface of* something, like a floor, a table etc. So you could say that the bird was standing *on* your balcony.

"At" usually means that you have reached the periphery of something. For example, you might arrive at your home, and *then* you go *in*. So if you are referring to the fact that the bird *comes to* your balcony, use 'at'.

"Of" *could* be used in some contexts. For example, you might say that a person is "a regular of this bar", but in such a context you would be referring to 'the bar' as an establishment rather than a location. In the same way, you could say "he's a regular customer *of mine*", even though *you* are not a location. This doesn't feel quite natural in the context of your balcony.

Comment: Also, “One of my balcony’s regulars”.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes I agree with that - it almost personifies the balcony and makes it more acceptable in the context.

Comment: Well, a location doesn’t have to be “personified” to be able to use a possessive with it, The church’s pews were made of oak. One of the school’s students won an award.

Comment: @ColleenV No, it doesn't have to be personified but your examples miss the point. A church and a school are both institutions, so you can speak of them as locations and buildings, but you can also speak of them as organisation and ascribe students or members to them. That isn't true of a balcony.

Comment: Dropping the possessive and using “balcony” as an attributive also works: One of the balcony regulars… One of living room’s chairs was broken. One of the upstairs room’s tenants was moving out. One of my finger’s knuckles. I think you are putting more “rules” around it than there actually are…

Comment: @Astralbee "That isn't true of a balcony." You could if there was some kind of (semi-)regular meeting held there.

Comment: @nick012000 Why don't you ask the OP? Maybe the annual general meeting of starlings is held there.

Answer (score 3):

Astralbee's answer is correct.
*at: destination

on: surface*

Additional nuance *might* be implied from common-use idioms.

at: as a social activity
"a regular *at* cards", "a regular *at* parties"
implies the balcony is an active social location

on: as status or importance
"a regular *on* television", "a regular *on* the dancefloor"
implies this bird is more memorable or more important than others.

Comment: I don't think it means the bird is more important or memorable - it just means that bird is usually on the balcony every day (or some other predictable time period). For example, I have a hummingbird that comes to eat every evening at my feeder - she's a regular. She's not prettier or more important than the ones that don't come every day, she's just more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Juliet stood ON her balcony, but Romeo stood AT her balcony.

Whose behavior does the bird's more closely resemble?

I don't believe "of" can be used idiomatically here.